# Get Notification React Native

Tags: react-native

I need to display the notification in my notification screen.

This is my code to getNotificationfrom the fcmToken but there is something wrong and I don't know if its in the function or in my screen code as its not displaying any notification on my screen , can you please help ? Thank you

````
  const getNotifications = async (props, u_id) => {
  var token = null;
  const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
  if (fcmToken) {
    token = fcmToken;
  }
  console.log(token);
  try {
    const { data } = await mainUrl(5000).get(url.noti_get_all);
    console.log(data);
    if (isvalidArr(data)) {
      setIncomingNotifications(props.currentDis, data);
    } else {
      setIncomingNotifications(props.currentDis, []);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (isUnauth(error)) {
      refreshRequest(props, () => getNotifications(props, u_id));
    } else {
      setIncomingNotifications(props.currentDis, []);
    }
  }
}; ```

NOTIFICATION SCREEN : 
This is a short part of the my notification screen where I display my notification in the return

 onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ isloading: true });
    if (this.props.user !== null) {
      getNotifications(this.props, this.props.user._id);
    }
    this.setState({ isloading: false });
  };
 
{isloading === true ? (
              SearchAndLocate()
            ) : notification.length < 1 ? (
              <View style={{ flex: 1, height: height - 300 }}>
                {this._noOrder()}
              </View>
            ) : (
              notification.map((item, key) => {
                const { selectedItems } = this.state;
                // const index = selectedItems.findIndex(
                //   element => element === item._id,
                // );
                // var read = -1;
                // if (
                //   item.read !== null &&
                //   item.read !== undefined &&
                //   Array.isArray(item.read) === true
                // ) {
                //   read = item.read.findIndex(itx => itx === this.state.token);
                // }
                return ()
````

Answer (score 0):

You should register for remote notification, you can use [react-native-notifications](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications) or [notifee](https://notifee.app) (paid for production).
here's a sample code

```js
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import { Notifications } from "react-native-notifications";

const registerNotification = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
    if (!enabled) return;

    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    console.log(fcmToken); // print it and use it to send notification from firebase

    Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications();

    Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedForeground(
      (notification, completion) => {
        showAlert({
          title: notification.payload.title,
          message: notification.payload.body,
          notification: notification,
        });
      }
    );
  };
```

on iOS you should add push noitification Capability
[image]